# How to check the user selections on dynamically generated radio buttons and check boxes in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

The following is my codes.  This is still work in progress; so, you will see some functions with empty contents.  Plus, this is my first Flex application; please bear with me.

This is a quiz application that gets the questions and answers to each questions from a ColdFusion web service.  There are three types of questions, True or False, Multiple Choice with single selection, and Multiple Choice with multiple selections.  So, based upon the question type, the application would dynamically generate the appropriate amount of radio buttons or check boxes for the users to select.  I got these working.  The problem that I am having is, I am not sure how to check what the users have actually selected.  In some other forums and posts on other web site, it said that I can use event.currentTarget.selectedValue to get the user selection.  But when I actually do it, I got a run-time error saying, "Property selectedValue not found on mx.controls.FormItem and there is no default value."  My question is, what do I need to do to capture the user selections?

Thanks in advance,

Monte

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
  creationComplete="initVars()">
    <fx:Declarations>       
      <s:RemoteObject id="CFCertService" destination="ColdFusion" source="CFCertExam.cfquiz">
        <s:method name="returnQuestions" result="resultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:method name="returnAnswers" result="answerHandler(event)"/>
      </s:RemoteObject>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.containers.FormItem;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.CheckBox;
            import mx.controls.RadioButton;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

            [Bindable]
            private var questionArray:ArrayCollection;
            private var questionType:String;
            private var answerItem:FormItem;

            [Bindable]
            private var currentQuestionCounter:int;

            [Bindable]
            private var answerArray:ArrayCollection;
            private var myOptionButton:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
            private var myOptionButton2:RadioButton = new RadioButton();

            private function initVars():void {
                currentQuestionCounter = 0;
                btnPrev.enabled = false;
                btnNext.enabled = false;
            }

            private function answerHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
                answerArray = event.result as ArrayCollection;
                var i:int;
                answerForm.removeAllChildren();
                answerItem = new FormItem();
                answerForm.addChild(answerItem);

                switch (questionType) {
                    case "True or False":
                    {   
                            myOptionButton.label = "True";
                            if (answerArray.getItemAt(0).Answer_Choice == "True") {
                              myOptionButton.value = 1;
                            } else {
                                myOptionButton.value = 0;
                            }


                            answerItem.addChild(myOptionButton);                            

                            myOptionButton2.label = "False";             
                            if (answerArray.getItemAt(0).Answer_Choice == "False") {
                                myOptionButton2.value = 1;
                            } else {
                                myOptionButton2.value = 0;
                            }
                            answerItem.addChild(myOptionButton2);                       
                            answerItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectionHandler);                            
                            break;
                    }

                    case "Multiple Choice (Single Selection)":
                    {
                        for (i=0; i<answerArray.length; i++) {
                            var myOptionButton1:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
                            myOptionButton1.label = answerArray.getItemAt(i).Answer_Choice; 
                            if (answerArray.getItemAt(i).Corect_Flag == "1") {
                                myOptionButton1.value = 1;
                            } else {
                                myOptionButton1.value = 0;
                            }                           
                            answerItem.addChild(myOptionButton1);                           
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    case "Multiple Choice (Multiple Selection)":
                    {
                        for (i=0; i<answerArray.length; i++) {
                            var myCheckBox:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
                            myCheckBox.label = answerArray.getItemAt(i).Answer_Choice;             
                            answerItem.addChild(myCheckBox);                            
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                answerForm.x = 380;
                answerForm.y = 200;
            }

            private function selectionHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                Alert.show(event.currentTarget.toString());
            }

            private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
                questionArray = event.result as ArrayCollection;

                txt1Questions.htmlText = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Text;
                questionType = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Type;
                btnNext.enabled = true;
                CFCertService.returnAnswers(questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_ID);
            }

            private function buttonEventHandler():void {
                CFCertService.returnQuestions();
                btnStartExam.enabled = false;
            }

            private function btnPrevEventHandler():void {
                currentQuestionCounter--;
                if (currentQuestionCounter == 0) {
                    btnPrev.enabled = false;
                }
                if (currentQuestionCounter < questionArray.length) {
                    btnNext.enabled = true;
                }
                txt1Questions.htmlText = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Text;
                questionType = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Type;
                CFCertService.returnAnswers(questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_ID);

            }

            private function answerReturnHandler(questionIndex:int):void {
            }

            private function btnNextEventHandler():void {
                currentQuestionCounter++; 

                if (currentQuestionCounter > 0) {
                    btnPrev.enabled = true;
                }
                if (currentQuestionCounter >= (questionArray.length - 1)) {
                    btnNext.enabled = false;
                }
                txt1Questions.htmlText = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Text;
                questionType = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Type;
                CFCertService.returnAnswers(questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_ID);

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Text id="txt1Questions" x="129" y="124"/>
    <s:Button id="btnStartExam" label="Start Exam" click="buttonEventHandler()" x="370" y="54"/>

    <mx:Form id="answerForm"/>
    <s:Button x="129" y="436" label="Previous" id="btnPrev" click="btnPrevEventHandler()" enabled="false"/>
    <s:Button x="642" y="436" label="Next" id="btnNext" click="btnNextEventHandler()" enabled="false"/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: You should always format your code as code, otherwise XML tags will not be shown at all.  Use the {} button or indent 4 spaces.  Also, just pasting your entire program will most likely not help getting an answer.  Narrow down your question to those lines of code relevant to the problem - no one wants to have to recreate your software to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I clicked on the Code Sample icon and then I pasted the codes there.  Should I click on some other icon instead?  And as far as pasting the entire program is concerned, it was late and I was not thinking.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `currentTarget` references the UIComponent that you add the event listener to, which you added to the FormItem and not the RadioButtons.

**Two Options**

1. If you want to continue to add the event listener to the FormItem, you should use `target` instead of `currentTarget` to obtain the reference to the actual item clicked, rather than the UIComponent with the listener on it.  However, you should be aware that if you add anything else to the FormItem (e.g., Labels, RichText, etc), those items will also trigger the event listener when clicked.
2. The other option is to add event listeners (they can all use `selectionHandler`) to each of the RadioButtons and then `currentTarget` will work fine.

Also, you might want to use a [RadioButtonGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html) for those questions which only allow a single selection.  Then you would only need to use the Event.CHANGE on the RadioButtonGroup to trigger your `selectionHandler`.

**Additional Resource**

Check out the [video on event bubbling](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/flex-in-a-week-day-2/understanding-the-event-object-and-bubbling/) from the Flex in a Week series.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Per your advise, I am using RadioButtonGroup and Event.Change to trigger my event handler.  Things are looking good!